# Scanner issue: NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

I'm making a class to read an object from file, that's earlier saved to file(.txt format) but I receive the following error when trying to load the file:

> java.util.NoSuchElementException

The method is made in such way so the user should be able to enter the name of the file. Even though it has been tried to debug abit and also just refer to the file itself with the name already given (not taking input). This is how the method looks:

```
public void load( String filename ) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    final String FIELD_STOP = ":";
    String loadFile;
    loadFile = filename +".txt";

    FileReader ansfil = new FileReader( loadFile );
    Scanner fileIn = new Scanner( ansfil );
    fileIn.useLocale( new Locale( "en" ) );

    System.out.println(loadFile);
    fileIn.useDelimiter( FIELD_STOP );
    int size;

    try
    {
        while( fileIn.hasNext() )
        {
            size = fileIn.nextInt();
            archive = new CDarkivImplemented( size );
            CD readIn = new CDImplemented();

            for( int i = 0; i <  size ; i++ )
            {
                readIn = new CDImplemented();
                readIn.title = fileIn.next();
                readIn.artist = fileIn.next();
                readIn.genre = CD.interpretGenre( fileIn.next() );
                readIn.publisher = fileIn.next();
                readIn.year = fileIn.nextInt();
                readIn.ID = fileIn.nextInt();
                archive.addCD(readIn);
            }

        }

    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println( "Wrong! : " + e );
        System.exit(1);
    }
    fileIn.close();
}
```

Comment: what line is giving the error?

Comment: Are you sure that you have integers separated by colon in your file ? There might be some other String instead of integer..Check your file contents.

Comment: The file contains nothing but this:
50:
test:test:pop:test:2012:3301:
First value is the total size put off for the archive. Then the first value equals the string, 2nd is artist, 3rd is the genre, 4th is publisher, then it is year and an generated Id function from when i created the object from earlier. This was just a quick test for the methods load and save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is that while loop for? As i infer from your comment about the file format you probably do not need this, and it might be causing the error due to it looping one more time after the last element has been read.

Answer (score 2):

I *suspect* this is the problem:

```
for( int i = 0; i <=  size ; i++ )
```

That loop will execute `size + 1` times, which probably isn't what you meant. Try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

and see if that helps...

(As an aside, I'd declare the `readIn` variable *inside* the loop - there's no need to have it outside. I'd also use a `finally` block to close the file.)

Comment: I'm afraid that it didn't do the trick. I also thought of that earlier, but it still gives me the same exception.

Comment: @Ole-MortenHeggertveit: Then your file just doesn't contain as much data as it claims to. There's not a lot we can do to help you with that - you should debug through and check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void load( String filename ) throws FileNotFoundException {
   final String FIELD_STOP = ":";
   final String loadFile = filename +".txt";
   try( FileReader ansfil = new FileReader( loadFile )) {
      Scanner fileIn = new Scanner( ansfil );
      fileIn.useLocale( new Locale( "en" ) );
      System.out.println(loadFile);
      fileIn.useDelimiter( FIELD_STOP );
      int size;
      while( fileIn.hasNext()) {
         size = fileIn.nextInt();
         archive = new CDarkivImplemented( size );
         for( int i = 0; fileIn.hasNext() && i < size; i++ ) {
            String title = fileIn.next();
            if( ! fileIn.hasNext()) break;
            String artist = fileIn.next();
            if( ! fileIn.hasNext()) break;
            String genre = fileIn.next();
            if( ! fileIn.hasNext()) break;
            String publisher = fileIn.next();
            if( ! fileIn.hasNext()) break;
            int year = fileIn.nextInt();
            if( ! fileIn.hasNext()) break;
            int ID = fileIn.nextInt();
            archive.addCD(
               new CDImplemented(
                  title, artist, genre, publisher, year, ID ));
         }
      }
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       System.out.println( "Wrong! : " + e );
       System.exit(1);
   }
}
```